# marklogic mlcp custom transform split aggregate document to multiple files

Tags: javascript, json, marklogic, mlcp

I have a JSON "aggregate" file that I want to split up and ingest as multiple documents into MarkLogic using mlcp.

I want to [transform the content during ingestion using javascript](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_55217).

My JSON file looks something like this:

```js
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {blobA}, {blobB}, {blobC} ......
    ]
 }
```

...and I want to run this file through MLCP so that each document contains an item in the array.

i.e. One document will contain {blobA}, another will contain {blobB}, and another will contain {blobC}....and so forth.

How do I write my custom .sjs transform module?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the example here:
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_26044

The original input document is expected to be of the following form:

```js
{ uri: string,
  value: node
}
```

That is also the expected output form for each document. You'll also want your return to be of type document-node, since you want mlcp to split it up and ingest it as JSON documents.

So, your .sjs custom transform module will look something like this....

```js
function splitFeatures(doc) {
  const features = doc.value.toObject().features;
  return xdmp.arrayValues(
    features.map(function(feature) {
      return {
        uri: '/path/itemhere-' + xdmp.random() + '.json',
        value: xdmp.toJSON(feature)
      }
    })
  );
}

exports.transform = splitFeatures;
```

As an aside, this is a [useful resource when working with JSON in MarkLogic](https://developer.marklogic.com/features/json).