# Big JSON file to be splitted into multiple sub files and ingest via mlcp

Tags: marklogic-10, mlcp

I have json file as below  -

```
{
"items" : [ {
  "book" : 'abc'
},
{
  "book" : '123'
},{
  "book" : 'xyz'
}
]

}
```

I used below mlcp command but getting error like "leading space".

mlcp.bat import -host localhost -port 7003 -username admin -password admin -input_file_path C:\CR -input_file_type delimited_json

what is the best way to load this json file as multiple file for each book field. So post ingestion I should have 3 files, one for each book field.

Comment: declare function mlcploadtest:transform(
  $content as map:map,
  $context as map:map
) as map:map*
{
        let $ncontent := map:map()
        for $root at $n  in map:get($content, "value")/items
        let $uri := xdmp:hash64(fn:string(fn:current-dateTime()))||$n||'.json'
        let $_:= map:put($ncontent,'uri',$uri)
        let $_:= map:put($ncontent,'value',$root)
        return $ncontent
};

Answer (score 0):

MLCP expects each line in the file of a `delimited_json` to be a line of JSON.

https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/mlcp-guide/en/importing-content-into-marklogic-server/creating-documents-from-line-delimited-json-files/line-delimited-json-overview.html

> A line-delimited JSON file is a type of aggregate file where each line is a self-contained piece of JSON data, such as an object or array.

It isn't going to parse the JSON doc and read the `items` array as separate docs.

You can achieve that in a [custom ingest transform](https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/mlcp-guide/en/importing-content-into-marklogic-server/transforming-content-during-ingestion.html) though. This similar question has an example demonstrating how to read the JSON and create a document for each item in an array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36506478/14419

Comment: Yes, I am using custom transform, and it works fine in my local but when I run the same mlcp command in server it throws an error. Function in below comments-

Comment: let $ncontent := map:map()
        let $result := 
            for $root in map:get($content, "value")/items
            let $uri := sem:uuid-string()||'.json'
            return 
                xdmp:document-insert($uri, $root,
                <options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert">  
                <permissions>{xdmp:default-permissions()}</permissions>
                <collections>
                <collection>MLCPSPLIT</collection>
                <collection>CROSSREFITEMS</collection>
                </collections>
                </options>)
        return $ncontent

Comment: What error do you see? If you expect help, details are important.

Comment: 24/01/16 00:16:36 WARN contentpump.TransformWriter: <error:format-string xmlns:error="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">syntax error, unexpected QName_, expecting $end:  </error:format-string>

Comment: the same json file, when I load it with mlcp/transformation in my local marklogic it is working fine.

Comment: That error is a syntax error. It's difficult to diagnose that without seeing the code.

Comment: The code is in above comment- 2nd one.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code snippet that you posted in that comment, but that is not a oomplete module (`$content` is not defined)

Comment: I got the issue, it was because of the xquery declaration missing in the header.

Comment: One more thing, do we have the option to get the "file name" in transformation function ? As I want to keep the filename as part of the URI